# How to check if the labelled regions are the same in two images?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation, scikit-image, image-morphology

So the idea is to write a precision and recall metric for segmentation task. The usual metrics for segmentation tasks calculate this metric by comparing the ground truth and prediction masks pixelwise. The way I want to calculate is that even if some part of the object in ground truth is predicted, then the whole object os considered as true positive.

The way I am currently approaching the problem is I am calculating logical and of the ground truth and predicted masks. Then using [skimage.measure.label](http://scikitimage.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html) to assign a unique id to each blob. Then I calculate True Positives, False Negatives etc. by using the number of blobs in both

```
and_mask = np.logical_and(gt, pred)
labels1 = measure.label(gt, neighbors=8, background=0)
labels2 = measure.label(and_mask, neighbors=8, background=0)
```

This works for most cases but in the case where my predicted mask for a blob is predicted in two parts, then performing logical_and on it gives me an extra object. This screws up my calculation of metrics.

Is there a way to prevent this and also, is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. I used measure.label to get the individual masks and then computed the iou with the gt masks. That's what I wanted to

```
    labels1 = measure.label(gt, neighbors=8, background=0)
        # loop over the unique components
        for label in np.unique(labels1):
            # if this is the background label, ignore it
            if label == 0:
                continue
            # otherwise, construct the label mask 
            labelMask1 = np.zeros(pred.shape, dtype="uint8")
            labelMask1[labels1 == label] = 255
            c, counts1 = np.unique(np.logical_and(labelMask1, pred, 
             where=255), return_counts=True)
            inter = np.sum(np.logical_and(labelMask1, pred, where=255)) / 
            np.sum(np.logical_or(labelMask1, pred, where=255))
```

Here's the rough algorithm if anyone's interested.

Comment: You’re not getting false positive this way.

Comment: I know this one is only for recall, for precision and getting false positives, the algorithm is quite similar except that I get the logical_and of individual masks in the predicted label and ground truth.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluation of segmentation is an active area of research, but some metrics already exist. My favorite is the variation of information. One key feature is that it doesn't depend on the number of labels in each image or the assignment of labels between images. This isn't yet in scikit-image, but we have a pull request open to include it:

https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/3354

You can check out that branch or copy the implementation from there, or just wait a bit and hopefully it'll be in the next release!

Comment: Thanks for this, the variation of information looks interesting but I need to understand what it represents before I start using it.

Comment: Of course! In case it helps, I wrote a brief introduction to VI in a paper of mine once, which might help. See "Results: 1. Evaluation" here: https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0071715#s3 The original VI papers by Marina Meila are also quite accessible but a bit more mathematical.

Comment: Great !, I'll check it out